# antlr4 lexer/parser conflict due to ambiguity

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse MS's dialect of SQL. According to the spec a 'top' must have brackets around its expression

select **top (@rows * 2)** a, b, c from ...

but as an exception these may be omitted if the value is an unsigned literal integer, thus

select **top 75** a, b, c from ...

I tried to embed this literal-integer special case in my parser (loosely):

**top_clause : 'TOP' [0-9]+ | 'TOP' '(' expression ')' ;**

So the first alternative is a pure lexer rule, the second is a parser rule. Since an integer constant is a valid expression, it chooses to parse it as an expression.

Question is, 1) can I force it to match as a lexer rule without predicates and 2) most importantly, should I?

My guess is I shouldn't - it is a blatant ambiguity (really, a fault in my grammar) and I guess I should match it as a pure parser rule (just "'TOP' expression") and sort it out after.
Advice welcome.

edit: amended per Matt Timmermans's point.

Comment: don't you want `'TOP' [0-9]+ | 'TOP' '(' expression ')'`  ?

Comment: Well, an expression is already defined, amongst other things, as **'(' expression ')'**, and because I expect to remove the lexer-only rule, I skipped them here (because I didn't want to require them if the rest of the expression was just an integer). But yes, you're correct. Will edit.

Comment: now it's not ambiguous

Comment: Stone me. Feel like a fool :(  Regarding the other part of the question, Should I Do It?, do you have an opinion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm familiar with these kinds of systems, but not antlr4, so I can't answer your specific question.  But there's no reason to do anything weird here, so you probably shouldn't :)

Comment: "so you probably shouldn't" - I'm going with that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you actually want to achieve, but my guess is that you want to allow e.g. whitespaces between TOP and the digits. If you define this as a lexer rule you would have to explicitly specify whitespaces there. With a parser rule this is not necessary because (again I'm guessing here) you have a lexer rule that skips whitspaces.

What I recommend is that you always define your literals as lexer rules (no 'TOP' in a parser rule, no digits) and keep the top_clause as it is, just with your new lexer rules (and a small refactoring):

```
DIGITS: [0-9]+;
TOP: 'TOP';
OPEN_PAR: '(';
CLOSE_PAR: ')';

top_clause: TOP (DIGITS | OPEN_PAR expression CLOSE_PAR);
```

Comment: Hi, no it's not whitespace merely that the 'top' construct has a special case of no-brackets-needed-if-just-digits; should I treat that special case with its own lexer rule? Matt Timmermans says no and it sounds right. RE. the lexer rules, I was simplifying for this post; all my lexing is done with named rules, with the sole exception of '(' and ')' which per your urging I will now en-rule-ify.

Comment: Small note - ANTLR's lexer is so capable I've caused myself problems by using it instead of the parser for complex structures. Hint to others - put all the structure in the parser & keep the lexing simple.